# Why can't I make the dropdown menu take the features of the main menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have downloaded a HTML template that I really like and would like to modify to my needs. The issue is that it doesn't have a dropdown menu....so I decided to add one to the HTML and create the CSS styling for it too.

[image]

Unfortunately this is what I get. The menu becomes extended downward and the dropdown menu items are persistently there. I am pretty sure that the problem is in the css file, but can someone please guide me through the steps on how to change/format the css to make that dropdown menu appear/disappear on hover and have the same format as the main menu?

This is the HTML code:

```
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Spanish</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">English</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">French</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">German</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
            <li><a href="#">Technologies</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        <!-- start soc_icons -->
    </nav>
```

This is the CSS part that I might have messed up a bit. :)

```
   /* menu */
.h_menu{
    padding: 0;
    background: #3B3B3B;
}
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    background: #3B3B3B;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover{
    background: #FF5454;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.nav > li {
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(39, 37, 37);
}
.nav > li > a {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
/* dropdown menu */

.nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    /* this is what orders the nested links to appear in a block under the main ul*/
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 32px;
    left:0;
}
.nav ul li:hover ul {
    /* this is what makes the dropdown menu appear on hovering over it*/
    visibility: visible;
}
.nav li:hover {
    background: #ff5454;
    /* main menu box changes to this color (also the submenus) on hovering over it, red in this case*/
    ;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you have messed up your css.

Comment: have a look at this... this can perhaps get you in right direction. although the question is slightly different. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997728/horizontal-menu-with-vertical-submenu-html-css-only

Answer (score 1):

You are targetting an element which is one "below" the one you want to target at:

```
.nav ul ul
```

changed to

```
.nav ul
```

but here the complete solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">French</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Technologies</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
/* menu */
.h_menu{
  padding: 0;
  background: #3B3B3B;
}
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  background: #3B3B3B;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover{
  background: #FF5454;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.nav > li {
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(39, 37, 37);
}
.nav > li > a {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* dropdown menu */
.nav ul {
  /* this is what orders the nested links to appear in a block under the main ul*/
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 32px;
  left: 0;
}
.nav li:hover ul {
/* this is what makes the dropdown menu appear on hovering over it*/
  visibility: visible;
}
.nav li:hover {
  background: #ff5454;
  /* main menu box changes to this color (also the submenus) on hovering over it, red in this case*/ ;
}
```